# winapi - WM_MEASUREITEM - how to determine an event source

Tags: winapi

I use a custom-drawn context menu (`MFT_OWNERDRAW`). I handle `WM_MEASUREITEM` and `WM_DRAWITEM` messages.

For the `WM_DRAWITEM` message, I can identify the event source based on the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` structure. It contains `hwndItem` - for menus, this member is a handle to the menu that contains the item.

The `MEASUREITEMSTRUCT` structure doesn't contain such information. Is it possible to somehow determine the event source for `WM_MEASUREITEM`?

EDIT: I can use `itemData` to send some custom struct. When handling `WM_MEASUREITEM`, I have to cast `ULONG_PTR` to my struct, eg:

`A* a = (A*)item->itemData`

What if `WM_MEASUREITEM` is sent for some other control with a different `itemData`, for example a `B` struct? How to determine that at runtime?

Comment: The [itemData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-measureitemstruct) field is yours. You can use it in any way you like.

Comment: Ok, please see Edit.

Comment: Have your `itemData` be identifiable, e.g. by making it point to a tagged union.

Comment: Could you please provide an example ?

Comment: Example of a tagged union: [INPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-input).

Comment: *if  is sent for some other control* you have *CtlID* and *itemID*

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`WM_MEASUREITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-measureitem):

> Contains the value of the CtlID member of the [`MEASUREITEMSTRUCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-measureitemstruct) structure pointed to by the lParam parameter. This value identifies the control that sent the WM_MEASUREITEM message. If the value is zero, the message was sent by a menu. If the value is nonzero, the message was sent by a combo box or by a list box. If the value is nonzero, and the value of the itemID member of the MEASUREITEMSTRUCT pointed to by lParam is (UINT) 1, the message was sent by a combo edit field.

The `CtlID` is the identifier of the combo box or list box and `itemID` is the identifier for a menu item or the position of a list box or combo box item `MEASUREITEMSTRUCT`.You can use them to distinguish different controls.